# Modifying toolstip formatter in highcharts of php

Tags: javascript

I have a data in the following format `["event",3],["status",998]`. I am using pie chart to display the data. In the tooltip I am getting the name and percentage but i want my tool tip to like `[event:3]`. How can I do that?

```
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    allowPointSelect: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    color: '#000000',
    connectorColor: '#000000',
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.point.percentage
    }
  }
}
},
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    data: [["event",2],["status",30]] 
  }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer as

```
                    formatter: function() {
                                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.point.percentage

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Browser share',
                        data: [["event",2],["status",30]] 
                    }]
```